# Cannot assign Object[] to Observable<Object[]>

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm currently bumbling my way through an Angular 4 project. I've manageed to overcome most errors myself, so far, however I cannot figure out this one.

I am trying to use *ngFor (async) to display a list of Observable objects.
However, I get the error **"Cannot assign Course[] to Observable< Course[] >"**, however I feel like my service is returning an Observable< Course[] >.

course-list.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { CourseCardComponent } from '../course-card/course-card.component';
import { CourseCardService } from '../course-card/course-card.service';
import { CourseCard } from '../course-card/course-card.model';
import { Observable }     from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-course-list',
  templateUrl: './course-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./course-list.component.css']
})
export class CourseListComponent implements OnInit {
  courseCards : Observable<CourseCard[]>;
  loaded = false;

  constructor(private http:Http, private coursecardService:CourseCardService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.coursecardService.getCourses()
    .subscribe(
      courses => {
        this.courseCards = courses;
        console.log(this.courseCards);
        this.loaded = true;
      },
      err => {
        console.log("Error", err);
      }
    )
  }
}
```

course-card.service.ts

```
import { Injectable }     from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable }     from 'rxjs/Observable';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

import { CourseCard } from './course-card.model';

@Injectable()
export class CourseCardService {
    // Returns this JSON data:
    // [{"firstName":"Jane"},{"firstName":"John"}]
    private URL = '/api/getcourses';

    constructor (private http: Http) {}

    getCourses(): Observable<CourseCard[]> {
        return this.http.get(this.URL)
            .map((response) => {
            let data = response.text() ? response.json():[{}];
                if(data) {
                    return data;
                }
            }
        )
        .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));
    }
}
```

And the HTML for the course-list component
Courses

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let course of courses|async">
    <app-course-card [name]='course.name' [wordcount]=0></app-course-card>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This part does return an `Observable<CourseCard[]>`:

> this.coursecardService.getCourses()

But then you are manually subscribing to it, and inside of the subscribe, courses is of type `CourseCard[]`. So when you try to assign `this.courseCards = courses;`, that's when you're getting the type mismatch.

The async pipe will do the subscription for you, so you can change your code to:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.courseCards = this.coursecardService.getCourses();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I read more about the .subscribe method. It returns a subscription object, I just needed to change it to:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.courseCards = this.coursecardService.getCourses();
  }
```

Comment: Instead of writing your own answer, you could accept the answer with the exact same piece of code that Nicholas Tower gave you :)

Answer (score 0):

Is your list properties name is correct? `let course of courses` or supposed to be 
`let course of courseCards`?

```
   <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let course of courseCards|async">
        <app-course-card [name]='course.name' [wordcount]=0></app-course-card>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Haha good spot, I found that after fixing the subscription problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

```
getCourses(): Observable<CourseCard[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.URL)
        .map((response) => <CourseCard[]>response.json())
        .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));
}
```